How do I create an AWS Glue Trigger using Terraform with Multiple Predicates?
I'm trying to create an AWS Glue conditional trigger using Terraform but am unable to find the correct syntax for creating the trigger to be dependent on the success of two other jobs.
I would like example_job_3 to be triggered by successful runs of both example_job_1 and example_job_2.
Terraform showing creation of example jobs.
resource "aws_glue_job" "example_job_1" {
  name         = "example_job_1"
  role_arn     = aws_iam_role.Glue_Role.arn
  command {
    name            = "glueetl"
    script_location = "s3://path/to/script1.py"
  }
}

resource "aws_glue_job" "example_job_2" {
  name         = "example_job_2"
  role_arn     = aws_iam_role.Glue_Role.arn
  command {
    name            = "glueetl"
    script_location = "s3://path/to/script2.py"
  }
}

resource "aws_glue_job" "example_job_3" {
  name         = "example_job_3"
  role_arn     = aws_iam_role.Glue_Role.arn
  command {
    name            = "glueetl"
    script_location = "s3://path/to/script3.py"
  }
}

I am unable to get past a terraform validate due syntax issues.
